# Issues with TB6612FNG with arduino on battery power

Tags: arduino, motordriver

I have a custom board with TB6612FNG and Atmega328P with arduino uno bootloader. When I program it, the motor controller works well with PWM control. However, when I switch power from USB power to battery power, the motor no longer works, it kind of jitters and no motor movement. However, if I update speed to 255 or -255, it works on full speed.

So to sum it up, the motor controller works nice at full speed irrespective of USB power or battery power. However, if I reduce speed to anything but 255 or -255, it just does not work on battery power, but only on USB power. When I connect both battery and USB power, even then it does not work on lower speeds.

Battery (VM) is connected to a regulator (1117 - 5V - VCC) which powers the board and the motor controller and direct power - VM is connected to TB6612FNG VM pin. Is this anything related to how battery power powers the chip and motor controller, or which reaches first, VM or VCC, or something like this?

Please find below code and also the schematic of custom board. Any help is appreciated.

```
    #define PWMA 5
    #define AIN1 10
    #define AIN2 4
    #define BIN1 7
    #define BIN2 8
    #define PWMB 6
    #define motor_A 0
    #define motor_B 1
    #define FORWARD 1
    #define REVERSE 0
    #define RIGHT 1
    #define LEFT 0

    void setup()
    {
      pinMode(PWMA, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(AIN1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(AIN2, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(PWMB, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(BIN1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(BIN2, OUTPUT);
      delay(5000);
    }

    void loop()
    {
      motor_brake();
      delay(1000);
      motor_drive(FORWARD, 150);  // if this replaced with 255, it works on battery also, but at full speed
      delay(1000);
      motor_brake();             
      delay(1000);
      motor_drive(REVERSE, 150); // if this replaced with 255, it works on battery also, but at full speed
      delay(1000);
      motor_brake();             
      delay(1000);
      motor_turn(RIGHT, 150, 150); // if this replaced with 255, it works on battery also, but at full speed
      delay(1000);
      motor_brake();
      delay(1000);
    }

    void motor_brake()
    {
      digitalWrite(AIN1, 1);
      digitalWrite(AIN2, 1);
      digitalWrite(PWMA, LOW);
      digitalWrite(BIN1, 1);
      digitalWrite(BIN2, 1);
      digitalWrite(PWMB, LOW);
    }

    void motor_drive(char direction, unsigned char speed)
    {
      if (direction == FORWARD)
      {
        motor_control(motor_A, FORWARD, speed);
        motor_control(motor_B, FORWARD, speed);
      }
      else
      {
        motor_control(motor_A, REVERSE, speed);
        motor_control(motor_B, REVERSE, speed);
      }
    }

    void motor_turn(char direction, unsigned char speed_A, unsigned char speed_B )
    {
      if (direction == RIGHT)
      {
        motor_control(motor_A, REVERSE, speed_A);
        motor_control(motor_B, FORWARD, speed_B);
      }
      else
      {
        motor_control(motor_A, FORWARD, speed_A);
        motor_control(motor_B, REVERSE, speed_B);
      }
    }

    void motor_control(char motor, char direction, unsigned char speed)
    {
      if (motor == motor_A)
      {
        if (direction == FORWARD)
        {
          digitalWrite(AIN1, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(AIN2, LOW);
        }
        else
        {
          digitalWrite(AIN1, LOW);
          digitalWrite(AIN2, HIGH);
        }
        analogWrite(PWMA, speed);
      }
      else
      {
        if (direction == FORWARD)
        {
          digitalWrite(BIN1, LOW);
          digitalWrite(BIN2, HIGH);
        }
        else
        {
          digitalWrite(BIN1, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(BIN2, LOW);
        }
        analogWrite(PWMB, speed);
      }
    }
```

[image: Arduino with TB6612FNG]